# Why use the ComponentResourceKey MarkupExtension?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I've written a lot of WPF styles and templates but never used the `ComponentResourceKey` markup extension.  I've never understood why I would need it.

I obviously read this [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/componentresourcekey-markup-extension?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

> Defines and references keys for resources that are loaded from
> external assemblies. This enables a resource lookup to specify a
> target type in an assembly, rather than an explicit resource
> dictionary in an assembly or on a class.

But I'm still not understanding what this buys me.  Either way I have to specify the target type.

For example, reading up on creating a [custom view for the ListViewControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/how-to-create-a-custom-view-mode-for-a-listview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8), I came across this article which uses a Style that starts off like this:

```
<Style x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey 
      TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type l:PlainView},
      ResourceId=myPlainViewDSK}" 
       TargetType="{x:Type ListView}" 
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBox}}"
       >
```

If this were my project, why would I not want to just start it off something like this?

```
<Style x:Key="MyViewKey" TargetType="{x:Type l:PlainView}"
```

Comment: "A ComponentResourceKey can be defined and used independently of knowing exactly where the TypeInTargetAssembly is defined..."

Comment: I do see that but (and I fully accept that maybe I'm just dense) but I'm not seeing how that makes the situation different.  Even in Microsoft's example above, they  mustrefer to the view with its namespace, as `l:PlainView` right?  All they're using is the namespace of `PlainView`.  So all they need to know is the namespace (`l:`) that it lives in.  And that's all I needed to know in my example too.  The namespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're making a project that *no one else will use*, then either approach is fine.

However, imagine you're making a control library, that *other people* will use.
Now, consider the resource lookup behavior for [StaticResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/systems/xaml-resources-overview?view=netdesktop-7.0#static-resource-lookup-behavior) and [DynamicResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/systems/xaml-resources-overview?view=netdesktop-7.0#dynamic-resource-lookup-behavior).

When you use a `string`-based `x:Key`, it is possible for there to be a "collision" with resource keys.  What if you use `MyViewKey` in your control library, *and your user* uses that key as well?  The user's key will be used - not yours.

Sometimes, this is desired - it allows the user to override your styles.  Other times, it's not.

`ComponentResourceKey`s create an unambiguous resource key.